# How to copy textField to OSX clipboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, copy, clipboard

I'm stuck here. I know how to copy and paste on the iPhone side of things but how can I copy contents from a textField to the global clipboard in OSX. I've been searching the web but there are really no examples. So let me explain in detail what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a NSTextField named helloField and I want to be able to copy the contents of this helloField to the global pasteboard by pressing a button. How can this be done and is there certain libraries I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

On iOS

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = helloField.text;
```

On OSX

```
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:helloField.stringValue forType:NSStringPboardType];
```

On macOS and Swift 3.x

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general()
pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.writeObjects([text as NSString])
```

Comment: Just figured out (on MonoMac for OS X) that the `clearContents` is required, otherwise the `setString` fails and returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Must omit parentheses on first line in Swift implementation: let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general

Comment: `NSStringPboardType` is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.14. Replace `NSStringPboardType` with `NSPasteboardTypeString`.

Answer (score 13):

For Swift 5

```
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.clearContents()
pasteboard.setString("string to copy", forType: .string)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Code to copy a string to the clipboard:**

```
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:copiedString forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```

`NSStringPboardType` is deprecated. There's a note in `NSPasteboard.h` about `pboard` types:

> Use of pboard types should be replaced with use of UTIs. Pboard types will be deprecated in a future release.

Also in the header file:

> APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeString NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6); // Replaces NSStringPboardType
>   ...
>   APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSStringPboardType; //Use NSPasteboardTypeString

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension for your String which supports iOS and macOS:

```
extension String {
    func copy() {
        #if os(macOS)
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.clearContents()
        pasteboard.setString(self, forType: .string)
        #else
        UIPasteboard.general.string = self
        #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cocoa macOS in Swift 3:

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general()
pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.setString("something", forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clipboard.set("some text")
```

class:

```
import AppKit

public class Clipboard {
    public static func set(text: String?) {
        if let text = text {
            let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
                pasteBoard.clearContents()
                pasteBoard.setString(text, forType: .string)
        }
    }
    
    @available(macOS 10.13, *)
    public static func set(url: URL?) {
        guard let url = url else { return }
        let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
        
        pasteBoard.clearContents()
        pasteBoard.setData(url.dataRepresentation, forType: .URL)
    }
    
    @available(macOS 10.13, *)
    public static func set(urlContent: URL?) {
        guard let url = urlContent,
              let nsImage = NSImage(contentsOf: url)
        else { return }
        
        let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteBoard.clearContents()
        pasteBoard.writeObjects([nsImage])
    }
    
    public static func clear() {
        NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()
    }
}
```